# Delete cache of server in Unity WebGL using C#

Tags: unity-game-engine, caching, unity-webgl

I am streaming some images, text and video assets from a server and whenever i assign HTTP address to a variable and later when i make changes to the link, it continues to load up the same HTTP link saved first time. I believe it has something to do with deleting server cache on end of the app.

Comment: If you have full control over your server, make sure to set the Expires/Cache-Control headers appropriately. Do you have this?

Comment: @NoobProgrammer No, i do not have control over the server

Comment: Okay try hard resetting it . ctrl + r.

Comment: I figured out the problem was with the declaration of my HTTP as public and once you do that it doesn't get updated from within the script, quite a small fix to use private declarations